# Apply theme based on user selection in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an idea to create a template sites that basically shows a different templates in web page. When user select particular template, The site should have changed to that theme selected by user at run time. Is there any plugin to change the theme dynamically in wordpress. If not kindly help how can we implement this ?

Answer (score 4):

This plugin called [theme preview](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-preview/) basically does what you want. Instead of actually switching the theme, it will preview it for the user, so only the actual user is affected of the theme change and not the whole environment!